# Laravel Eloquent model get unique user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model

I have this table, called "share":

[image: share table]

and this is the "user" table:

[image: user table]

So I get the list of shared item by "Share" model and the user associated with each entry:

```
class Share extends Model
{
    public function UserDetail()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

What I need is to return the users with `parent_id` 3 :

```
$user = Share::where('parent_id', '=', 3)->paginate(15);
```

Its returns everything but I need to return just unique users like this:

[image]

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please don't rate negative point. It's just my question.

Comment: Please explain again what you are trying to do. You want to take a `Share` and the get the users of that share ?

Comment: @EddyTheDove Yes, Exactly. I need to get the list of users from the share table. So I can show how many user I have.

Comment: so you are just trying to show how many times each item has been shared ? Or you are trying to see how many users you have in your database?

Comment: @EddyTheDove I need to show how many users I have shared item with on my database. So on the share table, I have parent_id and I need to get all users associated  with that parent_id for the share table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupBy` method to get unique users. Refer this link
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries

```
$user = Share::where('parent_id', '=', 3)->groupBy('item_id')->paginate(15);
```

Hopes answered your question.

Comment: It's not working. I tried this but it trow this error: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'app_db.share.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `share` where `parent_id` = 3 group by `email` limit 15 offset 0)`

Comment: @Martian.titan change it to `user_id`

Comment: I have added the code and also tried with `groupBy('email')` and unfortunately still same error. Really appreciate your follow up and helping

Comment: @Martian.titan try again. I think this one should be ok.

Comment: `select * from share where parent_id = 3 group by item_id limit 15 offset 0)`

Comment: Still same error. There is an issue with this: `'app_db.share.id' isn't in GROUP BY` can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, you want to take all the shares with a similar `parent_id` (3):

```
$shares = Share::where('parent_id', 3)->get();
```

And their users. Each share belongs to a user. But each user user can share many times but want to take the user only once. We could do

```
//Using eloquent
$users = Share::where('parent_id', 3)
->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'shares.user_id')
->select('users.id', 'users.email', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name')
->groupBy('users.id', 'users.email', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name')
->get();

//using Query builder
$users = DB::table('shares')
->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'shares.user_id')
->where('shares.parent_id', 3)
->select('users.id', 'users.email', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name')
->groupBy('users.id', 'users.email', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name')
->get();
```

This should give you a distinct list of users having shared `parent_id = 3`.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working properly. It'a just returning the parent_id 3 details instead of users details.